# std::holds_alternative variadic template

Tags: c++, c++17

Is it possible to wrap a `std::holds_alternative` to a variadic template to use it with more types?

For example:

```
std::variant<bool, int, double, std::string> var = 4;
bool r = std::holds_alternative<bool, double>(var); // holds either bool or double
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's doable with a simple fold expression.

```
template<typename... Alts, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool holds_any_of(std::variant<Ts...> const& v) noexcept {
    return (std::holds_alternative<Alts>(v) || ...);
}
```

Comment: Worth making it `constexpr` and `noexcept` like `std::holds_alternative`.

Comment: @DeiDei - Indeed!

Comment: Just a side question. I know `std::variant` does not exists in c++14 but would be something like that possible in c++14?

Comment: @Quest - It would be possible, but far less pretty. No fold expressions means we'd need to resort to more verbose methods.

Comment: @Quest Even worse: We'd have to fall back to resolving the template parameters recursively – but as there's no `constexpr if` either, we'd need a specialisation or overload to produce the recursive stop condition...

Answer (score 6):

No it's not possible. But you can roll your own:

```
template <class ...Request, class ...Types>
constexpr bool holdsAlternative(const std::variant<Types...>& v) noexcept
{
   return (std::holds_alternative<Request>(v) || ...);
}
```

to be invoked as you tried it with `std::holds_alternative`:

```
bool r = holdsAlternative<bool, double>(var);
```

Comment: `constexpr`, too, just as DeiDei proposed for StoryTeller's answer?